# zsh: Why do I get suspended background processes even when I have `stty -tostop`?

Tags: zsh, background-process, job-control, jobs, stty

I like my background processes to freely write to the tty. `stty -tostop` is already the default in my zsh (I don't know why, perhaps because of OhMyzsh?):

```
❯ stty -a |rg tostop                                                                                                      
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
```

But I still occasionally get my background processes suspended (this is not a consistent behavior, and I don't know how to reproduce it):

```
[1]  + 3479064 suspended (tty output)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A process can be sent that SIGTTOU signal (which causes that  message), when it makes a `TCSETSW` or `TCSETS` `ioctl()` for instance (like when using the `tcsetattr()` libc function) to set the tty line discipline settings while not in the foreground process group of a terminal (like when invoked in background from an interactive shell), regardless of whether `tostop` is enabled or not (which only affects *writes* to the terminal).

```
$ stty echo &
[1] 290008
[1]  + suspended (tty output)  stty echo
```

See `info libc SIGTTOU` on a GNU system for details:

> - Macro: int SIGTTOU
>
>   This is similar to `SIGTTIN`, but is generated when a process in a
>   background job attempts to write to the terminal **or set its modes**.
>   Again, the default action is to stop the process.  `SIGTTOU` is
>   only generated for an attempt to write to the terminal if the
>   `TOSTOP` output mode is set

(emphasis mine)

I believe it's not the only `ioctl()` that may cause that. From a cursory look at the Linux kernel source code, looks like `TCXONC` (`tcflow()`), `TCFLSH` (`tcflush()`) should too.

Comment: Is there any way to stop this SIGTTOU from being sent, or at least ignore it in my zsh programs? Will `trap -- '' SIGTTOU` work?

Comment: I just tested `trap -- '' TTOU SIGTTOU`. It doesn't work, the process will still get suspended.

Comment: @HappyFace, the problem would seem to be that you're trying to run a command that is meant to interact with the tty in background. Maybe you can run it as `cmd < /dev/null`. What's the command that is causing you trouble?

Comment: I don't really know what is the problem causer. (I tested `trap` using your own example of `stty echo`.) The setup is somewhat complex, and I have only once encountered this suspension error in it, though the error comes up in other contexts every few months. In that last time, a foreground `sleep 30` was suspended, while there was another script running in the background, which seemed to have been killed (with no messages). I didn't understand the situation at all. I am hoping that I can sweep the problem under the rug by just ignoring SIGTTOU, as I don't care who does what with the TTY.

Comment: Interestingly, this [link](http://curiousthing.org/sigttin-sigttou-deep-dive-linux) seems to indicate that ignoring SIGTTOU is possible in Python, and you can then change the terminal's configuration from the background.

Comment: Yes, zsh won't let you ignore the tty signals (TTIN, TTOU, TSTP, WINCH) even in non-interactive instances (which doesn't seem quite right to me), and zsh will even restore their default disposition on startup if they were previously ignored.

Comment: I had a similar issue (csh shell and bash script, the script worked fine until I added `stty -echoctl`, it would then **always suspend** when launched into background `... &`.  I searched for and tried many tips (different shell, redirecting output e.g. `... &>/dev/null` or `... | tee log`, setting `stty -tostop` etc.), none worked. **What finally fixed it was to add `</dev/null`** to when launching the script (even though the script takes no console input) as suggested by @StéphaneChazelas in a comment above. Once the stdin was redirected, the script could be launched in the background again.