# How to make backgrounded `watch` execute command on change

Tags: background-process, watch

I wanna use `watch` on certain commands and files (e.g. `w`), having it run in the background and notify me of any change. I've tried the following:

```bsh
(watch -g cat tmp && echo "changed") &
```

However, nothing happens when I change the contents of `tmp` and `watch` only exits on change when I foreground it with `fg`.

Is there a way to have `watch` running in the background and notify me of a change?

Comment: this is not what `watch` is for.   watch is for repeatedly running the same command and displaying its output.   you probably want to either pipe the output of `tail tmp` into, e.g., an awk script that exits on the first new line, or use `inotify` to monitor changes in a file.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way would be via `inotifywait` in `-m`onitor mode, i.e. running permanently instead of exiting after the first recorded event. Specify an `-e`vent like file/directory modification to watch - or do not to show all events like, opening, accessing, writing etc.. See `man inotifywait` for more about possible events.

```
$inotifywait -m -e modify tmp &
$echo 1 >> tmp
tmp MODIFY
```

The drawback is that in this version you do not execute a command on your own, but merely get the standard notification. For explicitly executing a command and idefinitely watching the file/directory, something like this would work (using `-q`uiet mode):

```
while ((1)) ; do \
   inotifywait -q -e modify tmp && echo "tmp was changed" \
done &
```

Answer (score 1):

`watch` is not designed for what you want to do.

At some point `watch` tries to reconfigure the terminal. Being in the background [it gets SIGTTOU](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/600460/108618) and stops. The whole job gets SIGTTOU.

In an interactive shell with job control you can see this when you invoke `jobs` afterwards. In `zsh` you would see a note `suspended (tty output)`. `jobs` in other shells may not be so informative.

In my tests I needed to redirect stdout and stderr away from the terminal:

```
(watch -g cat tmp >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "changed") &
```

If the original settings of the terminal include `tostop` then `echo` will trigger SIGTTOU when it tries to write. Run `stty -tostop` beforehand to make sure the settings allow `echo` to print to the terminal:

```
stty -tostop; (watch -g cat tmp >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "changed") &
```

Note other processes may configure the terminal on their own, therefore they may interfere.